# mysql sample employee database -- query for returning employees and their managers

Tags: mysql, sql

Having trouble creating query that returns result set that lists each employee and their manager.

If you're familiar with the employee db you know their is an employee table, a dept_manager table and dept_emp table where you can link the two previous tables.

My result set returns only one manager for everyone and one department.

I appreciate any help I can get!

```
SELECT d.dept_name AS 'Dept', 
CONCAT(em.last_name, ' ', em.first_name) AS 'Manager last, first',
CONCAT(e.last_name,' ', e.first_name, ' ', t.title) AS 'Employee last, first (title)'
FROM dept_manager AS dm

LEFT JOIN dept_emp AS de ON de.dept_no = dm.dept_no
LEFT JOIN departments AS d ON d.dept_no = dm.dept_no
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
LEFT JOIN employees AS em ON em.emp_no = dm.emp_no
LEFT JOIN titles AS t ON t.emp_no = e.emp_no 

WHERE 
dm.emp_no = e.emp_no
AND
dept_name = 'Sales'
OR 
dept_name = 'Marketing'
AND
dm.to_date >= '2012-05-07'
AND
t.to_date > '2012-05-07'
AND
de.to_date > '2012-05-07'

ORDER BY e.last_name, e.first_name

limit 1000
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the employee db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT d.dept_name department,
       CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name, ', ', t.title) employee,
       CONCAT(m.first_name, ' ', m.last_name) manager
  FROM employees e JOIN
       titles t ON e.emp_no = t.emp_no JOIN
       dept_emp de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no JOIN
       departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no JOIN
       dept_manager dm ON dm.dept_no = de.dept_no JOIN
       employees m ON dm.emp_no = m.emp_no
 WHERE (d.dept_name = 'Sales'
    OR d.dept_name = 'Marketing')
   AND dm.to_date >= '2012-05-07'
   AND t.to_date > '2012-05-07'
   AND de.to_date > '2012-05-07'
 ORDER BY employee
 LIMIT 1000
```

Always use parenthesis when you combine `AND` and `OR` in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this sql can help, I did not get the title out but I think it can be included in the second sub-query.
The whole idea is that we will try to get the emp_id and manager_id first, base on that, we will get related information by sub-query.

```
SELECT   (SELECT dept_name FROM departments WHERE dept_no = de.dept_no)
       , (SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) FROM employees WHERE emp_no = de.emp_no)
       , (SELECT CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) FROM employees WHERE emp_no = dm.manager_no)
FROM dept_emp de 
INNER JOIN dept_manager dm ON de.dept_no = dm.dept_no
```